# Get summary number from only visible table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which counts a total summary of all price table cells. This is not exactly what do I need. I need to count the summary from only visible rows. I use filtering by date range, once I change date it displays only dates from the selected date range, but the summary price is from the all rows. I need to implement the part of the code for visible table rows only and update the summary price in the span.

Any advice?

```js
function filterRows() {
  var from = jQuery("#datefilterfrom").val();
  var to = jQuery("#datefilterto").val();

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
  }

  from = from || "1970-01-01"; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || "2999-12-31";

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  jQuery("#table tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = jQuery(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD.MM.YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none"; // [] for inclusive
    jQuery(tr).css("display", visible);


    //summary start
    var table = document.getElementById("table"),
      sumVal = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
    }

    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Sum Value = " + sumVal;
    console.log(sumVal);
  });

  //summary end

}
jQuery("#datefilterfrom").on("change", filterRows);
jQuery("#datefilterto").on("change", filterRows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Date from</h4>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true">
    <h4>Date to</h4>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
  </div>
</div>

<span id="val"></span>

<table id="table" class="sortable">
  <tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>20.10.2020</td>
<td>20</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>21.10.2020</td>
<td>25</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>22.10.2020</td>
<td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks like when I select date range in HTML (so I need to get summary from only this selected tr)

[image]

I think there need to be some condition added here

```
sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the rows inside the `.each()` loop that's already looping through the rows?

Comment: Im little newbie in js. So I use some code which I found on the forum and tried to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops. You're already looping through the rows with `.each()` to make them visible or invisible, you can calculate the total in that same loop. After you determine if the row should be visible, use that variable in an `if` statement to add to the total.

jQuery has a built-in function `.toggle()` that will switch the visibility of an element. You can make `visible` a boolean variable instead of a `display` style value, then use that as the argument to `.toggle()`. Then you can use this same value in the `if` condition.

Make your access to columns less dependent on the table layout by using classes instead of column indexes. Use `jQuery(tr).find(".price")` to access the price column, for instance.

Use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to distinguish the headings from the table data, then use `tbody` in the `.each()` loop to only process data rows.

```js
function filterRows() {
  var from = jQuery("#datefilterfrom").val();
  var to = jQuery("#datefilterto").val();

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
  }

  from = from || "1970-01-01"; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || "2999-12-31";

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);
  var sumVal = 0;
  jQuery("#table tbody tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = jQuery(tr).find(".date").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD.MM.YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, []));

    jQuery(tr).toggle(visible);
    if (visible) {
      sumVal += parseInt(jQuery(tr).find(".price").text());
    }

    $("#val").text("Sum Value = " + sumVal);
  });
}

jQuery("#datefilterfrom, #datefilterto").on("change", filterRows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Date from</h4>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true">
    <h4>Date to</h4>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
  </div>
</div>

<span id="val"></span>

<table id="table" class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td class="date">20.10.2020</td>
          <td class="price">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td class="date">21.10.2020</td>
          <td class="price">25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td class="date">22.10.2020</td>
          <td class="price">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: On live website I use 7 child elements under tr. Price is located under the 7th child. When I set eq to 6 or 7 I get NaN value into the price summary, dont you know why?

Comment: I recommend assigning classes to the `td` elements, instead of counting them with `.eq()`. Then you can use `jQuery(tr).find(".price")` and `jQuery(tr).find(".date")`

Comment: I did it and still getting Nan

Comment: sumVal += parseInt(jQuery(tr).find(".price").text());

Comment: Make sure you only loop over data rows. I've split the table into `thead` and `tbody`.

Comment: could you please update the answer with the working solution which loop over the data rows please? Thanks

Comment: I already did in my last edit.